# Concrete example for comparing Rxjs event handling and Promise

Tags: rxjs

All:

I am very new to Rx.js( I heard this name from a tech meeting ), what im curious about is how to use it in real project(or say what is its usercase), and could anyone give me an example in which situation that a job Rx.js can do but Promise can not do(or just much easier to do in Rx.js)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague and open-ended. I recommend doing some reading, but if you want the short version:

Observables...

- Return a logical "infinite" number of values and a "completion" when this "infinite sequence" concludes, or throw an error
- Have a Creation/Subscription/Disposal lifecycle
- Can actually model a series of HTTP requests and their cancellation
- Are based on functional programming techniques and are reactive
- Are very good for modeling async data flows
- Are lazily evaluated based on subscribers

Promises...

- Return a single value asynchronously or reject/throw an error
- Are created and then by definition either resolve or reject
- Can model a single HTTP request that will be fulfilled
- Are not really FP based (there are multiple GH issues about this, they are almost all full of drama and aren't very much worth reading)
- Can only model single tasks
- Are eagerly evaluating by design

Some may mistake this as an attack on Promises, but Promises are usually **good enough** for single-value async. But Rx users probably don't like Promises because they feel like they only have a subset of features with less features compared to Observables.